# Как сделать расположение вкладок в TabControl на разных позициях

Tags: wpf, xaml

Имеется TabControl с например тремя вкладками хочу расположить их так две слева сверху одна слева снизу.

Как на изображении
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется макет

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab1" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab1 content" />
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab2" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab2 content" />
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab3" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab3 content" />
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

С C# разбираюсь вторую неделю, потому может коряво. Объединил информацию полученную c [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e602e5ae-657f-4c86-87c7-a5040874c29a/how-to-change-tabpanel-to-dockpanel-in-tabcontrol?forum=wpf) и [wpf-tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/ru/70/%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-tabcontrol/wpf-tabcontrol-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/#).

Используется два стиля, один - чтобы расположить вкладки, второй чтобы изменить их вид

[image: пример]

```
        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Width="300" Margin="45,20,447,196">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabControlNormalBorderBrush" Color="#8C8E94"/>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,4,4,4"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F9F9F9"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" IsItemsHost="true" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#8C8E94" CornerRadius="4,0,0,4" Margin="0,0">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        Margin="10,2"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="aaa" Content="aaaaa" ></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="bbb" Content="bbbbb" ></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="ccc" Content="ccccc" ></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="ddd" Content="ddddd" ></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Header="eee" Content="eeeee" ></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

---

Ещё один вариант, больше похож на то, что спрашивали: прямоугольные вкладки с отступами сверху и снизу

[image: пример]

```
        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="69,33,0,51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="353">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabControlNormalBorderBrush" Color="#8C8E94"/>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,4,4,4"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F9F9F9"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" IsItemsHost="true" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#8C8E94" CornerRadius="4,0,0,4" Margin="0,0">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        Margin="10,2"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="aaa" Content="aaaaa" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="bbb" Content="bbbbb" ></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="ccc" Content="ccccc" ></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="ddd" Content="ddddd" ></TabItem>
            <TabItem DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Header="eee" Content="eeeee" Margin="0,0,0,5"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```